# Obtain user followers using only user id

Tags: r, twitter

I have a large dataset of Twitter users ids. I would like to obtain the followers of all of them. I am working with R library `twitteR`.
As far as I understand, I need to get user objects using `lookupUsers` and then use `getFollowerIDs` to get the followers of every one of them.

As I have a large dataset, it would be faster if I could retrieve the followers providing not the user object, but only user id. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that [rtweet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/) library allows that.
User id can be used as a parameter of the `get_followers` function.